Convertir Caracteres especiales ñ y tildes en MariaDB11 y PHP 5.2
Hola amigos de stackoverflow.
Poco recurro a ustedes, pero en este caso estoy algo pensativo con una problemática con una actualización de base de datos y servidor que hicimos hace poco.
Trabajamos con cPanel y al quedarse obsoleta la versión de cloudlinux 7 decidimos migrar a cloudlinux9 actualizando de mysql 5.7 a mariadb 11.
La lectura de los caracteres especiales de la base de datos se leía bien anteriormente, pero ahora nos aparecen directamente como caracteres especiales, encontré un código dentro del software que hace una especie de transformación de estos caracteres, pero al parecer no está funcionando.
Ahora mi consulta es, por base de datos. ¿Puedo convertir todos estos caracteres para que queden correctamente en UTF-8 de alguna manera y que sea masivo?
He buscado varias soluciones, la idea es que se pueda lograr de manera masiva, ya que son 20 bases de datos cada una con 400 tablas con la afectación descrita, también he tratado con el utf8_decode y encode, pero no los convierte correctamente y en algunos casos donde se encripta la información al traerla directamente de la base de datos truncada, al desencriptarla aparece incorrecta.
Les comparto el código que no está funcionando después de la actualización:
$UTF8_LOWER_TO_UPPER = array(
  0x0061=>0x0041, 0x03C6=>0x03A6, 0x0163=>0x0162, 0x00E5=>0x00C5, 0x0062=>0x0042,
  0x013A=>0x0139, 0x00E1=>0x00C1, 0x0142=>0x0141, 0x03CD=>0x038E, 0x0101=>0x0100,
  0x0491=>0x0490, 0x03B4=>0x0394, 0x015B=>0x015A, 0x0064=>0x0044, 0x03B3=>0x0393,
  0x00F4=>0x00D4, 0x044A=>0x042A, 0x0439=>0x0419, 0x0113=>0x0112, 0x043C=>0x041C,
  0x015F=>0x015E, 0x0144=>0x0143, 0x00EE=>0x00CE, 0x045E=>0x040E, 0x044F=>0x042F,
  0x03BA=>0x039A, 0x0155=>0x0154, 0x0069=>0x0049, 0x0073=>0x0053, 0x1E1F=>0x1E1E,
  0x0135=>0x0134, 0x0447=>0x0427, 0x03C0=>0x03A0, 0x0438=>0x0418, 0x00F3=>0x00D3,
  0x0440=>0x0420, 0x0454=>0x0404, 0x0435=>0x0415, 0x0449=>0x0429, 0x014B=>0x014A,
  0x0431=>0x0411, 0x0459=>0x0409, 0x1E03=>0x1E02, 0x00F6=>0x00D6, 0x00F9=>0x00D9,
  0x006E=>0x004E, 0x0451=>0x0401, 0x03C4=>0x03A4, 0x0443=>0x0423, 0x015D=>0x015C,
  0x0453=>0x0403, 0x03C8=>0x03A8, 0x0159=>0x0158, 0x0067=>0x0047, 0x00E4=>0x00C4,
  0x03AC=>0x0386, 0x03AE=>0x0389, 0x0167=>0x0166, 0x03BE=>0x039E, 0x0165=>0x0164,
  0x0117=>0x0116, 0x0109=>0x0108, 0x0076=>0x0056, 0x00FE=>0x00DE, 0x0157=>0x0156,
  0x00FA=>0x00DA, 0x1E61=>0x1E60, 0x1E83=>0x1E82, 0x00E2=>0x00C2, 0x0119=>0x0118,
  0x0146=>0x0145, 0x0070=>0x0050, 0x0151=>0x0150, 0x044E=>0x042E, 0x0129=>0x0128,
  0x03C7=>0x03A7, 0x013E=>0x013D, 0x0442=>0x0422, 0x007A=>0x005A, 0x0448=>0x0428,
  0x03C1=>0x03A1, 0x1E81=>0x1E80, 0x016D=>0x016C, 0x00F5=>0x00D5, 0x0075=>0x0055,
  0x0177=>0x0176, 0x00FC=>0x00DC, 0x1E57=>0x1E56, 0x03C3=>0x03A3, 0x043A=>0x041A,
  0x006D=>0x004D, 0x016B=>0x016A, 0x0171=>0x0170, 0x0444=>0x0424, 0x00EC=>0x00CC,
  0x0169=>0x0168, 0x03BF=>0x039F, 0x006B=>0x004B, 0x00F2=>0x00D2, 0x00E0=>0x00C0,
  0x0434=>0x0414, 0x03C9=>0x03A9, 0x1E6B=>0x1E6A, 0x00E3=>0x00C3, 0x044D=>0x042D,
  0x0436=>0x0416, 0x01A1=>0x01A0, 0x010D=>0x010C, 0x011D=>0x011C, 0x00F0=>0x00D0,
  0x013C=>0x013B, 0x045F=>0x040F, 0x045A=>0x040A, 0x00E8=>0x00C8, 0x03C5=>0x03A5,
  0x0066=>0x0046, 0x00FD=>0x00DD, 0x0063=>0x0043, 0x021B=>0x021A, 0x00EA=>0x00CA,
  0x03B9=>0x0399, 0x017A=>0x0179, 0x00EF=>0x00CF, 0x01B0=>0x01AF, 0x0065=>0x0045,
  0x03BB=>0x039B, 0x03B8=>0x0398, 0x03BC=>0x039C, 0x045C=>0x040C, 0x043F=>0x041F,
  0x044C=>0x042C, 0x00FE=>0x00DE, 0x00F0=>0x00D0, 0x1EF3=>0x1EF2, 0x0068=>0x0048,
  0x00EB=>0x00CB, 0x0111=>0x0110, 0x0433=>0x0413, 0x012F=>0x012E, 0x00E6=>0x00C6,
  0x0078=>0x0058, 0x0161=>0x0160, 0x016F=>0x016E, 0x03B1=>0x0391, 0x0457=>0x0407,
  0x0173=>0x0172, 0x00FF=>0x0178, 0x006F=>0x004F, 0x043B=>0x041B, 0x03B5=>0x0395,
  0x0445=>0x0425, 0x0121=>0x0120, 0x017E=>0x017D, 0x017C=>0x017B, 0x03B6=>0x0396,
  0x03B2=>0x0392, 0x03AD=>0x0388, 0x1E85=>0x1E84, 0x0175=>0x0174, 0x0071=>0x0051,
  0x0437=>0x0417, 0x1E0B=>0x1E0A, 0x0148=>0x0147, 0x0105=>0x0104, 0x0458=>0x0408,
  0x014D=>0x014C, 0x00ED=>0x00CD, 0x0079=>0x0059, 0x010B=>0x010A, 0x03CE=>0x038F,
  0x0072=>0x0052, 0x0430=>0x0410, 0x0455=>0x0405, 0x0452=>0x0402, 0x0127=>0x0126,
  0x0137=>0x0136, 0x012B=>0x012A, 0x03AF=>0x038A, 0x044B=>0x042B, 0x006C=>0x004C,
  0x03B7=>0x0397, 0x0125=>0x0124, 0x0219=>0x0218, 0x00FB=>0x00DB, 0x011F=>0x011E,
  0x043E=>0x041E, 0x1E41=>0x1E40, 0x03BD=>0x039D, 0x0107=>0x0106, 0x03CB=>0x03AB,
  0x0446=>0x0426, 0x00FE=>0x00DE, 0x00E7=>0x00C7, 0x03CA=>0x03AA, 0x0441=>0x0421,
  0x0432=>0x0412, 0x010F=>0x010E, 0x00F8=>0x00D8, 0x0077=>0x0057, 0x011B=>0x011A,
  0x0074=>0x0054, 0x006A=>0x004A, 0x045B=>0x040B, 0x0456=>0x0406, 0x0103=>0x0102,
  0x03BB=>0x039B, 0x00F1=>0x00D1, 0x043D=>0x041D, 0x03CC=>0x038C, 0x00E9=>0x00C9,
  0x00F0=>0x00D0, 0x0457=>0x0407, 0x0123=>0x0122,
); 

$UTF8_UPPER_TO_LOWER = @array_flip($UTF8_LOWER_TO_UPPER);


function utf8_strtolower($string)
{
    if(function_exists('mb_strtolower'))
        return mb_strtolower($string,'utf-8');
    
    global $UTF8_UPPER_TO_LOWER;
    $uni = utf8_to_unicode($string); 
    for ($i=0; $i < count($uni); $i++)
    {
        if(isset($UTF8_UPPER_TO_LOWER[$uni[$i]]))
            $uni[$i] = $UTF8_UPPER_TO_LOWER[$uni[$i]];
    }
    return unicode_to_utf8($uni);
}

function unicode_to_utf8( $str )
{
    $utf8 = '';
    foreach( $str as $unicode ) 
    {
        if ( $unicode < 128 ) 
        {
            $utf8.= chr( $unicode );
        }
        elseif ( $unicode < 2048 )
        {
            $utf8.= chr( 192 +  ( ( $unicode - ( $unicode % 64 ) ) / 64 ) );
            $utf8.= chr( 128 + ( $unicode % 64 ) );
        }
        else
        {
            $utf8.= chr( 224 + ( ( $unicode - ( $unicode % 4096 ) ) / 4096 ) );
            $utf8.= chr( 128 + ( ( ( $unicode % 4096 ) - ( $unicode % 64 ) ) / 64 ) );
            $utf8.= chr( 128 + ( $unicode % 64 ) );
        }
    }
    return $utf8;
}

function utf8_to_unicode( $str ) 
{
    $unicode = array();  
    $values = array();
    $lookingFor = 1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen( $str ); $i++ )
    {
        $thisValue = ord( $str[ $i ] );
        if ( $thisValue < 128 ) $unicode[] = $thisValue;
        else
        {
            if ( count( $values ) == 0 )
                $lookingFor = ( $thisValue < 224 ) ? 2 : 3;
            $values[] = $thisValue;
            if ( count( $values ) == $lookingFor ) 
            {
                $number = ( $lookingFor == 3 )
                    ? ( ( $values[0] % 16 ) * 4096 ) + ( ( $values[1] % 64 ) * 64 ) + ( $values[2] % 64 )
                    : ( ( $values[0] % 32 ) * 64 ) + ( $values[1] % 64 );
                $unicode[] = $number;
                $values = array();
                $lookingFor = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return $unicode;
}

function is_utf8($str) {
    $c=0; $b=0;
    $bits=0;
    $len=strlen($str);
    for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
        $c=ord($str[$i]);
        if($c > 128){
            if(($c >= 254)) return false;
            elseif($c >= 252) $bits=6;
            elseif($c >= 248) $bits=5;
            elseif($c >= 240) $bits=4;
            elseif($c >= 224) $bits=3;
            elseif($c >= 192) $bits=2;
            else return false;
            if(($i+$bits) > $len) return false;
            while($bits > 1){
                $i++;
                $b=ord($str[$i]);
                if($b < 128 || $b > 191) return false;
                $bits--;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
} 

function maymin($cadena)
{
    if(!is_utf8($cadena))
    return ucwords(utf8_strtolower(utf8_encode(trim($cadena))));
    else
    return ucwords(utf8_strtolower(trim($cadena)));
}

function pinta_tildes($cadena) # 090908
{
    if(!is_utf8($cadena))
        return utf8_encode(trim($cadena));
    else
        return trim($cadena);
}

function pintabr($cadena)
{
    $cadena = trim(preg_replace("/\n/", "<br />", $cadena));
    if(!is_utf8($cadena))
    return utf8_encode($cadena);
    else
    return $cadena;
}

function spacer($height = '4')
{
    echo '<div style="width:100%;height:' . $height . 'px;display:block;border-collapse:collapse;border:0px solid;"></div>';
}


No se yo si estás intentando matar moscas a cañonazos... Dentro de la base de datos ¿en origen que collation tenian esas tablas? ¿y cual tienen ahora?

utf-8 decode (y encode) van a abandonarse, entonces puedes probar iconv():   iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", '¡ ¿ á é í ó ú Á É Í Ó Ú ñ Ñ ü Ü');    En caso de que necesites símbolos como el euro, yen, etc.:     iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", '£ € ¥ © ®');

Convendría ver un SHOW CREATE TABLE elNombreDeLaTabla así como verificar directamente si en la misma tabla los datos están o no bien codificados. Pues puede que sea un problema contextual, en cuyo caso debes revisar la conexión o el entorno PHP/HTML.

SOLUCIONADO:
Gracias al comentario de Juan Carlos pude resolver la novedad.
Se actualizaron los returns con la conversión, reemplazando utf8_encode por iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $cadena);
Se ha solucionado por completo. Gracias comunidad.

Para este tipo de casos conviene normalizar adecuadamente los datos así como configurar el entorno conforme a lo que quieras usar. No es una buena práctica hacer conversiones de los datos eternamente por al menos tres motivos: 1. Rendimiento: las conversiones tienen un costo, perceptible o no según qué contextos, pero lo tienen; 2. Riesgo de errores / obsolescencia: por ejemplo, utf8_encode, largamente utilizado en el pasado, es ya obsoleto y terminará fuera del núcleo de PHP un día u otro, lo cual hará que aquellos programas que lo usen resultarán en un error fatal ...

... ¿y si ocurre algo parecido con tu nueva función de conversión en un futuro? 3. Otro tipo de errores colaterales: que pueden ocurrir debido al contexto. Por ejemplo, imaginemos un código que depende de un determinado orden de los datos y tus conversiones no se hacen bien, por lo que sea, por motivos del charset que esté configurado en ese contexto, del coalesce de las tablas, etc, etc. Hablamos de errores que pueden ocurrir silenciosamente y propagarse en los datos, lo cual haría su corrección harto complicada.

En fin, que las conversiones ad aeternum son una pésima práctica. Configura bien el contexto y escribe tu código de conexión conforme a ese contexto. Si hace falta, normaliza los datos. Y así podrás desechar cualquier función de conversión. Para más detalles, puedes consultar esta respuesta donde se explica cómo hacer ambas cosas.

El detalle de ya normalizar teniendo esté problema en el código que me han entregado, es que se tendría que solucionar por lo menos unos 2 millones de registros en las bases de datos, de esta manera ya funcionaría bien. Por ahora los nuevos registros ingresados están funcionando correctamente, pero los pasados están teniendo esté problema. Por eso especificaba si es posible ejecutar alguna sentencia SQL que reemplace esto de manera masiva y convierta los caracteres a sus respectivas tildes y eñes.

Entiendo. Entonces estaríamos hablando de que buscas un código para normalizar los datos. Supongo que ya verificaste que el problema no es ni la configuración del cliente / servidor, ni de la configuración de las tablas (por eso te pedí que agregaras a la pregunta un SHOW CREATE TABLE) sino del contenido que en un momento dado se ingresó mal codificado en esa(s) tabla(s).
